# BeautifulSoup: how to get children of div tab

Tags: python, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Here is my code.

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 res = requests.get('http://www.snapdeal.com/products/computers-laptops?sort=plrty&')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
 price = soup.find_all('div', class_="product-price").children
```

I want to scrape data from this website but that div doesn't have class that is why I don't know how to do that then I found that you can find children of div tag but it is also not working and I'm trying to get all tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the desired price values.

You can use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and get the first child of every `div` having `product-price` class:

```
for price in soup.select("div.product-price > div:nth-of-type(1)"):
    print price.get_text(strip=True)
```

This would print:

```
Rs  33490Rs 42990(22%)
Rs  26799Rs 31500(15%)
...
Rs  41790Rs 44990(7%)
Rs  48000Rs 50000(4%)
```

[`nth-of-type` documentation reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Note that along with an actual price it contains the previous price which is on the strikethrough font. To get rid of it, get only top level text from the `div` by using `find()` with [`text=True`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) and [`recursive=False`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument):

```
for price in soup.select("div.product-price > div:nth-of-type(1)"):
    print price.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()
```

Prints:

```
Rs  33490
Rs  26799
...
Rs  41790
Rs  48000
```

You can go further and omit the `Rs` at the beginning and get the int (or float) price values:

```
for div in soup.select("div.product-price > div:nth-of-type(1)"):
    price = div.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()
    price = float(price.replace("Rs  ", ""))
    print price
```

Prints:

```
33490.0
26799.0
...
41790.0
48000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://www.snapdeal.com/products/computers-laptops?sort=plrty&')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
price_divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-price'})

for price_div in price_divs:
    child_div = price_div.find('div')    
    print child_div.text
```

Answer (score 1):

This get's the text within that div all striped clean:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('http://www.snapdeal.com/products/computers-laptops?sort=plrty&')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
price = soup.find_all('div', class_="product-price")

for p in price:
    soupInner = BeautifulSoup(str(p))
    print soupInner.find('div').find('div').get_text().strip()
```